# Laravel 8 share button

Tags: php, laravel

Hello Guys I've successfully installed laravel 8 share but the problem is that when I click on any of the social media handles it's doesn't share the page just reloads.
Here's my code:

```
    public function show($banner)
    {
        $categories = Category::all();
        $users = User::all();
        $usercom = \Auth::user()->id ?? null;
        $tags = Tag::orderBy('name','asc')->get();
        $banner = Banner::with('categories')->where('uniqueid', $banner)->first();
        $banner->incrementReadCount();
        $usageall = Usage::with('banners')->where('banner_id' , $banner->id)->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();
        $usages = Usage::with('banners')->where('banner_id' , $banner->id)->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get()->take(5);
        $comments = Comment::with('user')->where('banner_id' , $banner->id)->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();
        $trending = Banner::with('categories')->orderBy('views','desc')->get()->take(6);
        $shareComponent = \Share::page(
             URL::current(),
            'Hi Checkout my new Dp and tell me what you think',
        )
        ->facebook()
        ->twitter()
        ->linkedin()
        ->telegram()
        ->whatsapp()        
        ->reddit();
        dd($shareComponent);
        return view('banners.show',compact('banner','categories','tags','users','usercom','comments','usages','usageall','trending','shareComponent'));
    }
```

My View file

```
                        <div class="social-btn-sp">
                            {!! $shareComponent !!}
                        </div>
```

and route

```
Route::get('/banners/show/{row}',[BannerController::class, 'show'])->name('banners.show');
```

And also I didn't forget to do all these:

```
<?php

  return [

    'providers' => [
        ...
        ...        
        Jorenvh\Share\Providers\ShareServiceProvider::class,
    ];

    'aliases' => [
        ...
        ...                
        'Share' => Jorenvh\Share\ShareFacade::class,
    ];
  ];
```

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Jorenvh\Share\Providers\ShareServiceProvider"
```

This is what dd($shareComponent); shows me : [ShareComponent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBvhX.png)

You can click the above link to view.
Please guys I seriously need help on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Those `generatedUrls` don't look correct. Have you changed anything in the `laravel-share.php` config file?

Comment: No Sir if you want I can also post the file